# Dictionary of unique words and their position in a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, dictionary

I'm trying to build a 'database' of words and their corresponding tweet identifier.

My guess is that a dictionary is the best option for doing this.

Identifier, user, text, words get split on tab.

```
Example of input : 
1035421931321864192 SchipholWatch   RT @vinvanoort: Zo, ik heb getekend  Genoeg #geschiphol, hoogste tijd voor een eerlijk en duurzaam #luchtvaartbeleid    RT @vinvanoort : Zo , ik heb getekend  Genoeg #geschiphol , hoogste tijd voor een eerlijk en duurzaam #luchtvaartbeleid

1035421930541772800 ev4uam2 RT @AfshinEllian1: Kennelijk vinden ze daar aan die gezellige tafel normaal dat steltje barbaren onze grondwettelijke rechten bedreigen. Zouden we ook voor andere buitenwettelijke dreigingen moeten capituleren? Wat een door ons gesubsidieerde domheid! #laatop1 #cartoonwedstrijd  RT @AfshinEllian1 : Kennelijk vinden ze daar aan die gezellige tafel normaal dat steltje barbaren onze grondwettelijke rechten bedreigen . Zouden we ook voor andere buitenwettelijke dreigingen moeten capituleren ? Wat een door ons gesubsidieerde domheid ! #laatop1 #cartoonwedstrijd

Example of desired output:
{'exampleword' : ['1035421930541772800', '1235424930545772800']}
```

Current code :

```
def main():
    olist = []
    worddict = {}
    for line in sys.stdin:
        i,u,t,w = line.split('\t')
        splitword = w.split()
        olist.extend(splitword)


    for num,name in enumerate(olist):
        print("{} [{}]".format(name.strip(), num))

main()
```

So far i have tried iterating over the lines and adding splitword + i(which is the tweet identifier) to a dictionary, without succes.

Comment: Your desired output isn't a valid Python dictionary (seems to have two values for one key or a key without value)

Comment: It seems better to use identifier as key for dictionary (assuming that won't be repeating) and example words for it as a list of values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically what you want is to "reverse" a dictionary with `list` values to another dictionary with `list` values.

I abstracted from the actual tweet data since that would obfuscate the actual problem's answer.

A greedy implementation could be:

```py
import collections

def reverse_dict(input):
    output = collections.defaultdict(list)

    for key, val in input.items():
        for item in val:
            output[item].append(key)

    return output


def main():
    input = {
        'u123': ['hello', 'world'],
        'u456': ['hello', 'you'],
        'u789': ['you', 'world'],
    }

    output = reverse_dict(input)

    print output


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

As @Michael Butscher said, the expected output from your question is not a valid Python dictionary. The above code will output:

```sh
{'world': ['u789', 'u123'], 'you': ['u789', 'u456'], 'hello': ['u456', 'u123']}
```

Furthermore, as @Austin answered, approaching this problem using "brute force" won't necessarily be the best solution.

Comment: You could use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html?highlight=defaultdict#collections.defaultdict) to avoid having to check whether `item` is not in `output` and initializing the list manually.